# Update lead record on javascript button click in lighting

Tags: lightning, leads, update, record

I am new to salesforce lightning. I have a button in classic that update the lead status. But I am not been able to figure out how the same thing will be written in lightning. Here is my classic version code

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")}  
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/apex.js")} 

var leadObj = new sforce.SObject("Lead");  

leadObj.Id = '{!Lead.Id}';  
leadObj.Telesales_Converter__c = '{!$User.Id}';  
leadObj.Conversion_Date__c = new Date(); 
leadObj.Status = 'Bills Promised'; 


var result = sforce.connection.update([leadObj]);  

if (result[0].success=='false') {  
alert(result[0].errors.message);  
} else {  
window.parent.location.href="/{!Lead.Id}";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ressources provided by Salesforce to help you convert your Javascript Button. Also, there are different ways to convert your button, thus please see the references:

Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration

Lightning Experience Configuration Converter:
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/06/convert-javascript-buttons-to-lightning-friendly-alternatives-with-the-lightning-experience-configuration-converter.html

Scan Your Org for JavaScript Buttons and Links to get general suggestions: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_scan.htm&type=5

General information: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lcc_javascript_buttons_overview.htm&type=5